# Open Graph Check Users Permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I have a situation on my site where a user who has authorized my app can later opt to get their friends list so I want to check their current permissions before executing anything. I have found I can use

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

I want to check if the user has read_friendlists permission but I have not found any information about the object so I do not know how to write a condition against it. Facebook has an example of returned data on this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

but like I said I have not found a resource which describes the object.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If there's no `read_friendlists` entry in the response, you don't have that permission - write your condition based on the presence, or lack thereof, of the particular key (permission) you need

Comment: Thanks for the response. that is the problem I do not know how to write the conditional because I don't know what to write against. for example the user object has some could be done like if(response.name == mark){

Comment: in the case of the permission object I don't know the what goes after response.XXXX because I have not found documentation describing the object.